# Using Zurb Foundation in Kentico CMS Portal Engine

Tags: zurb-foundation, kentico

I need to use Zurb Foundation front-end framework and Kentico CMS v7's portal engine development model.  When I import the framework CSS into the CMS and apply the Foundation style sheet to a Page Template, the CMS styles and Foundation styles step on each other making the Design tab pretty much useless for the user:

No style applied:

[image]

Style applied:

[image]

I am wondering if I need to prefix styles in the Foundation CSS classes to try to prevent conflict, however my initial quick attempts didn't seem to have much affect.

Is there a way to include the Foundation CSS in a way that doesn't prevent portal engine development?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing i can think of now is to add the CSS conditionally.

Put

```
<%= CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.ViewMode != CMS.PortalEngine.ViewModeEnum.Design ? @"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""http://www.zurb.com/assets/foundation.top-bar.css"">" : "" %>
```

into a page layout. I tried to add this to layout of master page (Root document -> Master page -> Edit template properties -> Layout) and it works fine. But it will add the CSS to the . Unfortunately this code does not get resolved in head section of master page.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  This helps fix the CMSDesk issue however it still leaves the in page editing [borked](http://i.imgur.com/YxZOz73.png).

Comment: Well you can extend the condition with CMS.PortalEngine.ViewModeEnum.EditLive which serves for on-site editing.